# How can I properly divide viewport height on a screen?

Tags: html, css

I am a backend web developer with very little experience in front-end web designing.

I want help regarding viewport height "vh". The 100vh of the mobile screen is divided into two divs of 85vh+15vh.

On the Chrome browser of ios, it is showing up properly but on Android, it isn't properly shown (please find images below for proper understanding).

How I want -

[image: in the image you can see how 85+15vh is being properly shown on full 100vh perfectly divided]

---

but how it is -

[image: You can see how the 15vh gets hidden under, I assume the address bar is the culprit]

How can I fix this. Everything works fine on chrome when used in ios. Its only on android. Any help is appreciated.

Code Below :- 
HTML :-

```
 <section id="hero">
    <div class="bgVideo">
            <div class="heroKidsOverlay"></div>
        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="bgvid">
            <source src="assets/video/kids_section_banner.mp4" 
type="video/webm" />
            <source src="assets/video/kids_section_banner.mp4" 
type="video/mp4" />
        </video><!--video-->
        <div class="heroCaption">
            <h3>tailoring services for kids</h3>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">book an 
 appointment</a>
        </div><!--hero caption-->
    </div><!--bg video-->
</section><!--hero section-->

 <!--CUSTOMER CARE SECTION-->
 <section id="customerCareSection">
        <div class="customerCareCaption">
            <div class="ccinfo">
                <h3>Customer Service - 9 to 7</h3>
                <p><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" 
data-cfemail="355c5b535a755154474f5c5a5b565459591b565a58"> 
[email&#160;protected]</a></p>
            </div><!--ccinfo-->
        </div><!--customer care caption-->
    </section><!--customer section-->
```

css:-

```
#hero .bgVideo {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 85vh;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
#customerCareSection {
background-color: #F6454F;
height: 15vh;
position: relative;
border-top: 1px solid ghostwhite;
/* border-bottom: 1px solid ghostwhite; */
  }
```

Comment: You're not comparing like with like - when you scroll down (and the address header disappears), does the issue still occur?

Comment: no but that's not the point . I want it to look perfect at initial load itself like how it does on chrome for ios.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset the `margin` and `padding`. Try adding this css code to the top of your css file.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```